# Несколько доменов на сайт в wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

У меня установлен wordpress в режиме multisite. Мне нужно прикрепить несколько доменов к одному сайту в сети. Как это реализовать?

Comment: ну и причем тут wordpress? Паркуйте дополнительные домены к основному и они будут вести на тот же сайт. Или под "прикрепить несколько доменов к одному сайту в сети" вы имели ввиду что-то другое? Тогда опишите что именно.

Comment: @rdorn с WordPress это не прокатит. Все ссылки в базе хранятся как абсолютные. Если есть домен a.com, а мы сделали редирект b.com на него,  при попытке перехода между страницами b.com попадем на a.com. Потому ТС и задает вопрос.

Comment: @KAGGDesign в любом случае вопрос требует уточнения формулировки. В текущем виде не понятно - нужно несколько сайтов на одном движке или один сайт с несколькими именами. Последнее решается паркингом.

Answer (score 1):

Для этих целей есть плагин [WordPress MU Domain Mapping](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/). С его помощью можно задать несколько доменов, которые будут ссылаться на один сайт сети.