# Несколько доменов на один сайт

Tags: wordpress, домен

Возможно ли привязать к сайту на wordpress несколько доменов, чтобы все они при этом были равноценны? То есть если запись добавляется на сайт, её присваивается "domain1/название записи", "domain2/название записи". То есть по сути должен быть сайт разделяющий одну БД, ресурсы и равные между собой домены. Возможно ли такое?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Несколько доменов на сайт в wordpress](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/725246/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82-%d0%b2-wordpress)

Comment: @mymedia ты прежде чем цитировать мои ответы, разберись в репозитории WordPress. Тот плагин, что я раньше предлагал, не обновлялся уже 4 (четыре) года. Твой коммент надо бы минусовать, как вредный. Жаль, такой возможности нет на SO.

Comment: @KAGGDesign Если вы считаете, что тот ваш ответ более не актуальный, обновите его. И дело не в вашем ответе, а в повторном вопросе.

Answer (score 2):

Установите плагин [Multiple Domains](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-domain/).

Comment: Ответ ссылка. Приведите здесь хотя бы краткое описание плагина, покажите пример настройки.

Comment: @mymedia я знаю, что и как отвечать. Настроек в этом плагине ровно одна - список доменов.

Comment: И тем не менее, ответ в таком виде не соответствует правилам SO, дать просто ссылку недостаточно - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer. Покажите хотя бы скриншот.

Comment: @mymedia в даном случае - более чем достаточно. Это скорее вопрос не соответствует правилам SO. Ответ не "ссылка", а показано  готовое решение из оф репо ВП.